# how to use (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag to show saved item in data base

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to show the event that is saved in database and show drop down list with all available events to select item from them ,

controller:

```
   public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        TempData["CurrentPerformanceId"] = id;
        Performance performance = db.Performances.Find(id);
        if (performance == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var performancePerformers = performance.PerformerPerformances.Select(x => x.PerformerId).ToList();
        var availablePerformers = db.Performers.Where(s => !performancePerformers.Contains(s.PerformerId)).ToList();
        CustomPerformancePerformersModel cppm = new CustomPerformancePerformersModel();
        cppm.performanceObj = performance;
        cppm.AvailablePerformers = availablePerformers.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.PerformerId.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        //Events Dropdown autocomplete
        var availableEvnets = db.Events.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Deleted == false).ToList();
        var EventDropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in availableEvnets)
        {
            EventDropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.EventId.ToString() });
        }

        //Venues Dropdown autocomplete
        var availableVenue = db.Venues.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Deleted == false).ToList();
        var VenueDropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in availableVenue)
        {
            VenueDropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.VenueId.ToString() });
        }

        ViewBag.EventDropDownList = EventDropDownList;
        ViewBag.VenueDropDownList = VenueDropDownList;
        ViewBag.EventId = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Name", performance.EventId);
        ViewBag.VenueId = new SelectList(db.Venues, "VenueId", "Name", performance.VenueId);
        return View(performance);
    }
```

code :

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventId, "Event", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EventId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EventDropDownList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

that generate this drop down list with ,it's always start with "Amr Diab" event if another event is saved in database [image]

Comment: Please show code from your controller. What do you have in `ViewBag.EventDropDownList`?

Comment: i'm sorry , i edit my question

Comment: Also, where does the model come from? Are you sure, its EventId property contains the value from the database?

Comment: it's my mistake mr @NineBerry i update all code

Comment: Now please clarify your question - why events should not start with `Amr Diab`? You don't have it in database? What is expected first item?

Comment: because this performance have event name called "cariokee concerts" in data base 
and i want to appear cariokee concerts as it saved in database

Comment: my problem is it always appear amrdiab as title of event even if it saved another in database

Comment: @amalmansour I'm pretty sure that this event has name "Amr Diab" in database. Check your database please

Comment: i'm really sure ,it's cariokee concerts , and in all performances it appear amrdiab

Answer (score 1):

i just delete these 2 lines :

```
    ViewBag.EventId = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Name", performance.EventId);
    ViewBag.VenueId = new SelectList(db.Venues, "VenueId", "Name", performance.VenueId);
```

these 2 lines was rewrite EventId that saved in database with first choice in the list

thanks all